# Ctrl c Ctrl v copy paste in multi-term

Tags: key-bindings, copy-paste, multi-term

I want to be able to copy paste using `C-c` and `C-v` when I edit a file and in multi-term. After more than a few hours I gave up. I would be thankful if anyone could tell me what the recommended way for doing something like this is.  Here are some of the things I tried:

1. Putting

   ```
   (local-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save)
   (local-set-key (kbd "C-x") 'kill-region)
   (local-set-key (kbd "C-v") 'yank)
   ```

in my `find-file-hook`. This works for `C-x` and `C-v` but doesn't work for `C-c`. (I think this is because of the `C-c C-...` keybindings, but I don't know if there is some way to just overwrite those).

2. Defining a function that uses

   ```
   (if (or (eq major-mode 'term-mode) (eq major-mode 'eshell-mode))
   ```

to detect whether we are in a terminal or a file and then deactivates cua-mode or activates it. I added this function to some hooks but it got buggy, because this function was either called not enough or too often. Also

```
(add-to-list 'term-bind-key-alist '("some binding" . some command))
```

works for `C-v` and `C-x` but not for C-c.

Note: I know that `C-c` is normally terminal interrupt, but I put a `stty intr ^J` in my `.bashrc`.

3. Using `eshell` instead of multi-term: The Problem with the eshell is, that it's autocompletion is not as good as the autocompletion of bash. Bash can e.g. autocomplete git chec  to git checkout.

Note: I know that normal Emacs users use `M-w` and and `C-y to` copy-paste, but this would mess up my muscle memory when working with programs that use `C-c` `C-v` top copy-paste.

UPDATE: The following works:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-v") 'yank)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x") 'kill-region)
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-c") (kbd "M-w"))
(add-to-list 'term-bind-key-alist '("C-v" . term-paste))
```

Why is emacs so unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: 1. There are multiple questions in this question. Please post separate questions for them. 2. For `C-c`, `C-x`, `C-v` you likely want to use [`cua-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html) -- `C-h r g cua-mode`.

Comment: There is just one question in this post. How to make C-c C-v copy paste in a file and in multi-term. I know that I can activate cua-mode, but cua-mode does not work in multi-term.

Comment: Considering that `multi-term` is a terminal, you'll want your shell and software you use in it set up to treat `C-c` and `C-v` the way you expect. This doesn't sound like an Emacs problem to me.

Comment: Copy and paste is not handled by bash, but by emacs. E.g. in gnome-terminal copy is ctrl-shift-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-v") 'yank)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x") 'kill-region)
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-c") (kbd "M-w"))
(add-to-list 'term-bind-key-alist '("C-v" . term-paste))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to force this binding by reading the comments on the [wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm). Editing the multi-term.el file (if installed via M-x package-install) (located ~/emacs.d/elpa/multi-term-1.2/multi-term.el

Remove "C-c" from the term-unbind-key-list:

```
(defcustom term-unbind-key-list
  '("C-z" "C-x" "C-h" "C-y" "<ESC>")
  "The key list that will need to be unbind."
  :type 'list
  :group 'multi-term)
```

Change the term-bind-key-alist defaults, here I'm using C-c maybe you want C-c-c:

```
> (defcustom term-bind-key-alist  
>    '(
>     ("C-c" . kill-ring-save)
>     ("C-p" . previous-line)
>     ("C-v" . term-paste)
>       .....
```

[Recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1217249/8120802): `M-x byte-recompile-directory`

Restart emacs and `Ctrl-V` and `Ctrl-C` work as you want them to while in multi-term.

Comment: This works for multi-term, but I want to use C-c and C-v both in multi-term and when editing a file. Once I put a (cua-mode t) in my init.el I can't copy paste in multi-term.